# Is it true that $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in I} f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) = \sup_{x,t \text{ } \in I} |f(x)-f(t)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm solving a problem from baby Rudin about integration and I suspect that the following equation must hold:

$$\displaystyle \sup_{x \in I} f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) = \sup_{x,t \text{ } \in I} |f(x)-f(t)|$$

I guess I have a proof for it. Would you please check if my proof is right?

$$ \sup_{x \in I} f(x) - \inf_{x \in I} f(x) = \sup_{x \in I}f(x) - \inf_{t \in I} f(t) = \sup_{x \in I}f(x)+\sup_{t \in I}(-f(t))$$
$$=\sup_{x,t \in I}(f(x)-f(t))$$

But since both $x$ and $t$ can freely varry in the interval $I$, I guess that we have:
 $$\sup_{x,t \in I}(f(x)-f(t)) = \sup_{t,x \in I}(f(t)-f(x))$$

Therefore

$$\sup_{x,t \in I}(f(x)-f(t)) = \sup_{x,t \in I} |f(x)-f(t)|$$

My other justification for the last equality goes as this:

1. If for all $x,t$ in $I$ we have $f(x)=f(t)$ then $\displaystyle \sup_{x,t \in I}(f(x)-f(t)) = \sup_{t,x \in I}(f(t)-f(x))=0$.
2. Otherwise, then there exist $x,t \in I$ such that $f(x) < f(t)$. But in that case, $f(t)-f(x)$ will be positive and therefore we can always choose $x,t$ such that we can ignore negative differences.

Am I right?

I want to use this identity for integration problems in this way:

If a function $f$ is in $\mathfrak{R}(\alpha)$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist a partition $P = \{ a=x_0 , \cdots, x_n=b \}$ such that:

$$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha) < \epsilon$$

Therefore:

$$\large \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) \Delta \alpha_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x) \Delta \alpha_i < \epsilon$$

$$\large \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{x,t \text{ } \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} |f(x)-f(t)| \Delta \alpha_i < \epsilon$$

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is correct, and the first proof of it is correct as well. (I don't like the numbered item 2.)

If you want to be sure, fall back on the definition of supremum and infimum. For example: from $f(x)\le \sup_I f$ and $f(t)\ge \inf_I f$ it follows that 
$$ f(x)-f(t) \le \sup_I f - \inf_I f$$
for all $x,t\in I$. Interchanging the roles of $x,t$, obtain 
$$ f(t)-f(x) \le \sup_I f - \inf_I f$$
Therefore, $\sup_I f-\inf_I f$ is an upper bound for all $|f(x)-f(t)|$. This shows that 
$$\sup_{x,t\in I} |f(x)-f(t)|\le \sup_I f - \inf_I f \tag{1}$$
For the reverse inequality, pick $x$ and $t$ so that $f(x)>\sup_I f - \epsilon/2$ and $f(t)<\inf_I f+\epsilon/2$. Then
$$|f(x)-f(t)|\ge f(x)-f(t)>\sup_I f - \inf_I f - \epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, (1) holds as equality.